# Is it possible to perform multiple calculations on ActiveRecord groupings with joins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hypothetically, imagine you have a restaurant where customers leave tips for single specific reasons.  *e.g. great food, nice seats, big smiles, etc.*

For a single server I would like to know:

1. For each reason, what's the sum total of the received tips?
2. For each reason, how many tips were received?

I have implemented `acts_as_taggable_on` to tag each Tip. The models being:

```rb
# Tip -> Tagging <- Tag

class Tip
  has_many :taggings,  :as => :taggable
  has_many :base_tags, :through => :taggings, :source => :tag

  attr_accessible :amount_cents, :recipient_id
end

class Tagging
  belongs_to :taggable
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag
  has_many :taggings

  attr_accessible :name
end
```

**Question**: The following two queries work.  But I have a hunch that it should be possible to combine the two calculations into a single query:

```rb
Tip.joins(:taggings, :base_tags).where(recipient_id: server.id).group('tags.name').sum(:amount_cents)
# => {"great-service" => 2400, "strong-coffee" => 4500}

Tip.joins(:taggings, :base_tags).where(recipient_id: server.id).group('tags.name').count
# => {"great-service" => 6, "strong-coffee" => 9}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*5 years later* -- I would suggest, to my old self, to consider using a database view or a materialized view.

An option would be to use [Scenic](https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic). It is a Rubygem that integrates with ActiveRecord to create and manage database views in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

You could just run the query once then do the calculations with just Ruby methods:

```
results = Tip.joins(:taggings, :base_tag).where(recipient_id: server.id).all

total_sum = results.map(&:amount_cents).sum
total_count = results.count
```

Comment: Neat idea, but the query doesn't execute.  `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "tips.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: You may need to change the statement a bit to get the exact results you want.

Comment: I was hoping to utilize ActiveRecord's calculation methods to minimize the need to fully instantiate the models.  But this would work.

Comment: Yeah, in that case, you'd have to make two SQL calls - I can't think of a clean way to do it without a complex SQL statement.